# Is there a limit of databases per project in Firebase ? Is it possible to create them programmatically?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Since Firebase allows us to create multiple database in a project, is there a limit ?
I'm currently evaluating the way I could use Firebase to manage notifications, teams and presence.
Unfortunately, one database won't be enough. 
We may have more than 100 000 users at a time. Notifications and presence may produce more than 1000 writes/s.
I'm wandering if it's allowed to make 30, 60, 90, 120 shards with the Blaze plan ? 
It's not precised in the pricing page : https://firebase.google.com/pricing/
Is there a limit ?

Another question : is it possible to create new databases programmatically ?

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of databases you use has no impact on billing.  You will be billed for the usage of all your databases as a whole, as described in the billing page you linked.

It is currently not possible to create a database programmatically.

Comment: Is there a maximum number of databases that can be added to a project?

Comment: @user814425 If you have a new question, please post it separately.

Comment: It's the same as asked in this question, hence the comment rather than a duplicate

Answer (score 4):

There seems to be an undocumented limit of 1,000 databases per project for Firebase Realtime Database.

To support 10 million simultaneous users, I tried creating 100,000 databases.
Unfortunately, I ran into a limit of 1,000 databases, after which I could no longer create new databases.